# Why am I getting PHP Invalid JWT provided error?

Tags: php, jwt, push

keys generated from:
https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me/

response validated with: https://jwt.io/
[image]

Token being returned is valid! and yet I get the following error in chrome developer console:
"invalid JWT provided"

Why isnt my code working?

CODE:

```
function base64url_encode($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}



// Create token header as a JSON string
$header = json_encode(["alg" => "ES256","typ" => "JWT"]);

// Create token payload as a JSON string
$payload = json_encode(["aud" => "https://fcm.googleapis.com","exp" => time() + 3600,"sub" => "mailto:push@example.com"]);



// Encode Header to Base64Url String
$base64UrlHeader = base64url_encode($header);

// Encode Payload to Base64Url String
$base64UrlPayload = base64url_encode($payload);



// Create Signature Hash
$signature = hash_hmac("SHA256", $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, "PRIVATE_KEY", true);


// Encode Signature to Base64Url String
$base64UrlSignature = base64url_encode($signature);




// Create JWT
$token = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload . "." . $base64UrlSignature;



$key = "PUBLIC_KEY";


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/.....');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Ttl: 60";
$headers[] = "Content-Length: 0";
$headers[] = "Authorization: vapid t=".$token.",k=".$key."";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you use a private key to sign the token and a public key to verify, which can only be done for asymmetric signature algorithms, such as `RS256`. But as signature algorithm you choose `HS256`, which is a symmetric signature algorithm.

The `alg`claim in the header determines, which algorithm is used to verify the signature. Therefore the algorithm name in the header must match with the algorithm used for signing.

For symmetric algorithms, you have to use the same secret for signing and verification. The secret is just a string in no special form, eg. 'my-super-secret' or better something like '12z4104cntc4ta9c53434c9032trcbwuer8r'.

Now you can either

- use one secret for `HS256` instead of the public and private keys.
- change the algorithm to `RS256`, which would require some more code changes, because right now you calculate a HMAC-SHA256 (`HS256`) hash.

I highly recommend to use a JWT library. There [a list of libs](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io) for different languages and environments on https://jwt.io

Comment: When I change algorithm to RS256, then https://jwt.io/ fails and says Invalid Signature. So how exactly would i go about making my code HS256 format?

Comment: Whatever algorithm you use, you have to paste the public key or secret into the field in the rigjt column under verify signature on jwt.io. To verify a signature, you always nerd the key or secret. To use HS256, you just use the same key for both,signing and verification.

Comment: what exactly is not working? What did you change, what fails? Please show me your token and the key or secret you used.

Comment: in the original version of your question, before changing to `RS256` and then `ES256` you already had `HS256`, which is correct for HMAC-SHA256

Comment: HS256 did not work. I then followed a suggestion to change it to RS256, that did not work either. I then tried my code in the jwt.io validator and it set the type to ES256. None of those work.

Comment: It's crazy that so many websites use push notifications and yet there are no php resources online and nobody can help me figure this out

Comment: Please read my answer above again. Your original code, before any edits had a HS256 header and called a function for HMAC-SHA256 hashing. Only problem was the key, you can't work with public/private key pairs in HS256. If you want another alg, such as RS256, for which you need pub/priv keys, you also need to change the code. Just changing the alg header is not sufficient. And if there's still a problem, show me the JWT and key and I can have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So using HS256 you say the problem is the key. So I removed the k=.... from the authorization header and get the error: authorization header had no public application server key specified. Authorization header should have the following format: vapid t=jwtToken; k=base64(publicApplicationServerKey).     The problem seems to be the authorization header. What is the proper format for HS256

Comment: What a mess! Let me try to get it straight: Your question was, "why is my JWT invalid". My answer is: it's invalid, because you produce a HS256 signed token and send a public key to the api. HS256 doesn't work with private and public keys. Now if your API (I don't know anything about the API, and that was also not really clear in your question) needs a public key, the the token should probably be RS256 signed. But for that it's not enough to change the alg claim in the token header, there's much more to do in your code. Better use a JWT lib for PHP, that will give you a valid RS256 signed JWT.