# Push Notifications with PHP "invalid JWT provided" error

Tags: php, curl, jwt, push

I am trying to send a push notification to a pushSubscription endpoint and it is not working. Do you see any errors in my code?
Thanks for any help i receive in advance. I really hope you guys can help. I've hit a wall here

Public + Private Keys are randomly generated and not in production!

```
// Create token header as a JSON string
$header = json_encode(['typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => 'HS256']);

// Create token payload as a JSON string
$payload = json_encode(['aud' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com', 'exp' => time() + 72000, 'sub' => 'mailto:webpush@example.com']);

// Encode Header to Base64Url String
$base64UrlHeader = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($header));

// Encode Payload to Base64Url String
$base64UrlPayload = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($payload));



$public_key = 'BA-BIKtl82vO9x_T3BhBehW6ee_eLCruRNzB9hy9ltNucASORFDnewmVrEKsdmT3W_7bX87pXtWJhKYgPYBruOQ';
$private_key = 'REDACTED';




// Create Signature Hash
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $private_key);

// Encode Signature to Base64Url String
$base64UrlSignature = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($signature));

// Create JWT
$jwt = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload . "." . $base64UrlSignature;








/////SEND PUSH//////////

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.fcm.googeapis.com/fcm/send/.....');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = [];
$headers[] = 'Ttl: 60';
$headers[] = 'Content-Length: 0';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$jwt.'';
$headers[] = 'Crypto-Key: p256ecdsa='.$public_key.'';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You accidentally posted your private key. I've removed it for you, but you probably want to change it.

Comment: They are randomly generated and not in production

Comment: You asked this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963352/why-am-i-getting-php-invalid-jwt-provided-error/57963773#57963773) under a different account name and I already told you:  A: HMAC-SHA256(HS256) doesn't work with public/private key pairs. B:changing the alg value in the JWT header doesen't change the actual signature.  You can continue wasting your time asking the same question again and again, under whatever account. If you can not even accept a simple fact you won't make any progress in your work. I wasted more than enought time now, happy coding!

Comment: I'm not sure what the conspiracy theory is about but just because two posts used what seems like the same curl to php generator doesnt mean theyre the same person.and in regards to your answer here and the one you linked, it would be nice if you provide some code as context or something, as of now both answers are not helpful.